# It is possible to retrive data from firestore ussing toObject and object as parameter?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project in which I read data from Firestore. I have several collections so I use toObject successfully. Now, just for fun (and code saving) I would want to create a global function to be used for reading data and sending as a parameter the type of object I want to get.

I know I'm forgetting something but I cannot figure it out and maybe it is not even possible.

Here is my try but I get an error: Unresolved reference clase. I know I'm forgetting something but I cannot figure it out and maybe it is not even possible.

```
    fun todosRegistros(coleccion: String, orden: String, clase: Class<Any>):Any{
        // Cargamos los supermercados
        db.collection(coleccion).orderBy(orden).get().addOnSuccessListener { registros ->
            for (registroIt in registros) {
                val item = registroIt.toObject<clase>()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify `clase` as a generic type. What you should instead, is to call the [QueryDocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) function that takes as a parameter an object of type [Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/Class.html). So in your code, you should make the following change:

```
fun todosRegistros(coleccion: String, orden: String, clase: Class<Any>):Any{
    // Cargamos los supermercados
    db.collection(coleccion).orderBy(orden).get().addOnSuccessListener { registros ->
        for (registroIt in registros) {
            val item = registroIt.toObject(clase)
            //                              
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I think I understand. What you're looking for is called [generic functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-functions). So in code it should be:

```
fun <T> todosRegistros(coleccion: String, orden: String, clase: Class<T>):T{
    // Cargamos los supermercados
    questionsRef.orderBy(orden).get().addOnSuccessListener { registros ->
        for (registroIt in registros) {
            val item = registroIt.toObject(clase)
            //                              
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call the function using:

```
todosRegistros("Tipo","nombre", Class<Tipo>)
```

Also, don't forget to add the following import:

```
import java.lang.Class
```

Comment: Thanks!! I think I'm getting close. Now when I call the function I receive a "type mismatch" error: _Required Class <Any> found Class <Tipo>_ 

   `todosRegistros("Tipo","nombre", Class<Tipo>) ` 

Tipo is one of the several class that I created to manage the data to be writen or read from firestore
`data class Tipo(val nombre: String? = null, val url: String? = null)`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Work fine for me!

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) So can I help you with other information?

Comment: No so far. Thanks Alex, I learnt so much from others of your other posts (you saved my life with coroutines in kotlin) thanks